# mirror monitors with split screen?

Tags: windows, display, presentations, mirroring

I want to mirror half of my laptop's screen to the VGA output going to a projector, so I can see and control the other half, but the audience can't. The point is to create presentation notes (I'm not working with powerpoint)

I'm using windows 7.

Comment: What software are you using to show your presentation? It will be easier to give specific answers if we know what you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who is the manufacturer of your video card? The software provided by the manufacturer has this ability in their control software (i.e. Catalyst Control Center for ATI chipsets). If you find the manufacturer of your graphics processor and go to their website (not the PC manufacturer website) and download the full driver and control software package for the device, you will then have the ability to do what you need in that software.

For ATI: http://sites.amd.com/US/GAME/DOWNLOADS/Pages/downloads.aspx

For Nvidia: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us

Intel: http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx?iid=subhdr+dnlds_drivers

Comment: i have nvidia and i found nview. after enabling it, i have the functionality i need. great! thanks.

Comment: glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Simply press **Windows Key + P**, and set the screen to "Extend." Then you can drag the part you want over to the 2nd screen, and keep your private stuff on one.

Comment: But then my presentation is only on the projector, and no easy way to see it (my back is  to the screen). That's why I want mirroring

Comment: Ah, that would be an issue then. I came across this now: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=211482 Its a virtual desktop manager, you may be able to use this

Answer (score 1):

Found this: http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Unfortunately, it is not free.

Answer (score 0):

You might simply use the built-in functionality of PowerPoint.

First set your screen setup to extended screen using Windows-Key + P key combination. Then open PowerPoint and go to the `Slide Show` ribbon. Here have a look at the `Monitors` section. Make sure to enable the `Use Presenter View` checkbox. Then select the screen on which you would like to present the slides.

If you start your presentation now (`F5`) you should be presented the presenter view on one of your screens. This includes some clock to keep your timeframe as well as a big preview of what your audience sees as well as previes/thumbnails of your following slides so you know what's next and avoid sentence like "this you will see on the next slide" while actually on the next slide you have to revise it since you forgot that you've inserted another slide ;). It also shows your notes you made in slide design mode. So you can put all your comments to the slide notes and have them available easily during the presentation.

You can even switch to other programs (`Alt-Tab`...) without showing your audience what you're doing. The presentation screen will always just show your slides.

Note: In PowerPoint previous to PowerPoint 2007 the presenter view can be enabled via the Slideshow menu. Sorry I don't have it available here right now but I am sure you will find the correct entry.

Comment: While that is a very concise answer, he specifically mentions that he is not using PowerPoint to make his presentation.

Comment: Ups, my bad. Should have read the question correctly. Somehow I understood that he's using PP while he actually states that he is NOT using PP. Sorry for that. Well, someone might find this answer searching google looking for a solution with PP. So it might be helpful then. My apologize for posting off-topic then.